# How do I transfer traces and measurements from ECS to ElasticSearch?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, amazon-ecs, pulumi, open-telemetry

I want to transfer the traces and measurements for AWS ECS. I have made a script where I use aws-otel-collector collect traces and measurements.

```
export const service = new awsx.ecs.FargateService("backend", {
    taskDefinitionArgs: { 
                          taskRole: role,  
                          containers: {  
                                         otelCollector: {   
                                                             image: image: "docker.io/amazon/aws-otel-collector",
                                                             essential: true,
                                                             logConfiguration: {
                                                                                   logDriver: "awslogs",
                                                                                   options: {
                                                                                               "awslogs-group": "/ecs/ecs-aws-otel-sidecar-collector",
                                                                                               "awslogs-region": region,
                                                                                               "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs",
                                                                                               "awslogs-create-group": "true"
                                                                                            }
                                                                               }
                                                          },
                                      
    
                                         logRuter: {          
                                         
                                           image: "docker.io/amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest",
                                           essential: true,
                                           firelensConfiguration: {
                                                                    "type": "fluentbit",
                                                                    "options":{
                                                                                 "enable-ecs-log-metadata":"true"
                                                                               }
                                                                   },
                                           logConfiguration: {
                                                                logDriver: "awslogs",
                                                                options: {
                                                                            "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                                                                            "awslogs-group": "bakend-log",
                                                                            "awslogs-region": region,
                                                                            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "fluentbit"
                                                                         }
                                                              },
                                            memoryReservation: 50
                                            },

                                           backend: { 
                                                       image: 'steinko/helloworld-backend',
                                                       portMappings: [ backendLb ],
                                                       logConfiguration: {
                                                                            logDriver: "awsfirelens",
                                                                            options: { 
                                                                                         "Name":"es",
                                                                                         "match":"*",
                                                                                         "Port": "9200",
                                                                                         "Host":"efk-elastic",
                                                                                         "Logstash_format":"on",
                                                                                         "Replace_dots" :"on",
                                                                                         "Retry_limit":"false",
                                                                                         "Type":"doc",
                                                                                         "Suppress_Type_Name": "On",
                                                                                         "Cloud_ID": "My_deployment:xxxxxxxxxx",
                                                                                         "Cloud_Auth":"elastic:xxxxxxxxx",
                                                                                         "Index": "backend-index",
                                                                                         "tls": "On",
                                                                                         "tls.verify": "Off"
                                                                                         
                                                                                     }
                                                                        },
                                                       dependsOn: [
                                                                      {
                                                                           containerName: "otelCollector",
                                                                           condition: "START"
                                                                      }
                                                                 ]
                                                     }   
                                                
                                    },                
                                  
                        },
......
```

I found out that one can use Dataprepper to transfer [traces](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/build-an-observability-solution-using-managed-aws-services-and-the-opentelemetry-standard/). How to transfer traces and measurements to eleaticsearch?

Comment: BTW: you can use public ECR (https://gallery.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector) + (cheaper) Arm architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Configure [OTLP exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/exporter/otlpexporter) in your [aws-otel-collector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/open-telemetry-elastic.html) and point it to your Elasticsearch APM server. See your [ES APM doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/open-telemetry-elastic.html) how to do that.